# Why is my FBX export missing animation information?

Tags: animation, baking, .fbx

I have a scene with baked animations, so all of the meshes have their keyframes baked in. I am trying to export this as an FBX to use it in Unity. But no matter how I tweak the export settings, the animations are all gone after the export and then reimport.

I made a simplified version of only one model in the scene, here he is with all his keyframes:
[image]

Here are my export settings which are the default settings right now:
[image]

And here's the same mesh reimported, but without any animation data:
[image]

Only the single keyframe of the animation is being exported where the little blue indicator stands (which is the 98th keyframe in this case).

I did use a trick described here: [How to import lattice modifier animation to unity?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/243903/how-to-import-lattice-modifier-animation-to-unity/287119#287119)
Thus I exported everything ad MDD and reimported it to create shapekeys and bake the animation. I don't know if this makes a difference but I have used this method before and it did work, I must be missing something this time.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem, at the FBX export I had to uncheck "All Actions", and it fixed the problem, the animation-data is finally being exported with the mesh.